# HTML5 drag and drop content type?

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I need to know the content or type of data being dropped into a drop area. If its selected text or a file. With files I can tell with the extensions but I cant tell apart if its text or a file. Ima JS noob.

Answer (score 0):

you can't actually drop a selected text anywhere. You can drop *its container*.

Anyway, you have to be more specific on what you need exactly: the class?

If you are using the html5 drag and drop you can send a text data that the drop event recipient will receive. You could pass the object type of the dragged element for example, so you have it available afterwards.

Comment: text = e.dataTransfer.getData('Text');
  if (files === null || files === undefined) {
   opts.error(errors[0]);
   return false;
  }
  if(typeof text == "String"){
   $('.previewBox').html(e.dataTransfer.getData('Text'));
   console.log(e.dataTransfer.getData('Text'));   
  }

Comment: Srry, e.dataTransfer.getData was really all I needed to check for. but the above code wouldnt work. Its suppose to check if the .getData('Text') is set, like empty or not. Ive tried using the lenght property on text eg text.lenght > 0 but it still dnt work .

Comment: the getData("text") result is always a string, even if you pass an image content..